# Как проверить , что строковый индекс полностью совпадает с одним из строковых индексов?

Tags: javascript

Как проверить , что строковый индекс полностью совпадает с одним из строковых индексов?

Такие варианты должны получаться, но test проверяет только частичное совпадание:

```
if (/1|2|3|4|5|6/.test("31") ) false
if (/1|2|3|4|5|6/.test("1") ) true
if (/1|2|3|4|5|6/.test("13") ) false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте символы начала (^) и конца строки ($), а также сгруппируйте скобками, чтобы обозначить, что указанные вариации нужно искать целиком. Например:

```
console.log(/^42|314$/.test("42")); // true — трактуется как «либо начинается на 42, либо оканчивается на 314»
console.log(/^42|314$/.test("43314")); // true
console.log(/^(42|314)$/.test("42")); // true — либо 42, либо 314
console.log(/^(42|314)$/.test("43314")); // false
```

Итоговый ответ:

```
console.log(/^(1|2|3|4|5|6)$/.test("31")); // false
```

Проверить онлайн: https://regex101.com/r/kW5Mol/1